# After a integer data type and consecutive two character type. The 2nd character data type skips....Why?

Tags: c++, types, integer, character, primitive-types

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n=0;
    char name[20];
    char address[50];

    cout<<"Enter a Number";
    cin>>n;

    cout<<"Enter a Name ="; // HERE
    gets(name);

    cout<<"Enter a Address=";
    gets(address);

    cout<<"Number ="<<n<<endl;
    cout<<"Name = "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Address = "<<address<<endl;
}
```

It has one Integer type and two array of char type..when the program reach at ("Enter a name") why the compiler skip it without showing any problem.

Comment: If someone knows then kindly help me plz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n=0;
char name[20],c;
char address[50];
cout<<"Enter a Number";
cin>>n;
c = getchar();
cout<<"Enter a Name =";
gets(name);
cout<<"Enter a Address=";
gets(address);
cout<<"Number ="<<n<<endl;
cout<<"Name = "<<name<<endl;
cout<<"Address = "<<address<<endl;
}
```

Here, I have only performed one modification : taking a character input after the number is entered. This character stores the **\n** or the **Enter** you press after typing the input. Earlier, the Name field stored the **\n** and hence input skipped to the next field, but now we have used a buffer character to store it.

Comment: very Helpful. when i study this problem i found another way to solve this...if we use this fgets(name,20,stdin); with fgets(name)...then this problem will clear...

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use `cin` to get the integer, the newline you press to end the input is left in the input buffer, so when you next get a line the `gets` function will see this newline and read it as an empty line.

You can ask `cin` to ignore input until (and including) next newline with

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Brother will u plz explain me in simple way  or recommend me something to read... related to that topic.  Because i am a newbie